# Docker registry with self signed certificate fails

Tags: docker, docker-registry, self-signed-certificate

My goal is to have a docker registry running on a raspberry pi (behind the `rpi` hostname), me being able to push images from my linux PC on the same network. I'm following this guide: https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#use-self-signed-certificates

I did the following steps on my rpi:

1. `mkdir -p certs`
2. `openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha256 -keyout certs/domain.key -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:rpi" -x509 -days 365 -out certs/domain.crt`
3. `docker run -d --restart=always --name registry -v $HOME/certs:/certs -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443 -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key -p 443:443 registry`

Steps on my PC:

1. `scp pi@rpi:certs/domain.crt ca.crt`
2. `sudo mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/rpi:5000/`
3. `sudo mv ca.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/rpi:5000/`

Now, when I try pushing an image `docker push rpi:5000/test-image`, it fails with the following:
`Get "https://rpi:5000/v2/": dialing rpi:5000 with direct connection: connecting to 192.168.1.201:5000: dial tcp 192.168.1.201:5000: connect: connection refused`

If I tag the image with the 443 port `docker push rpi:443/test-image` I get this error: `Get "https://rpi:443/v2/": x509: certificate is valid for 227b7008fe5910b8b4b0563bb8ebcb9e.708221ab4c2f3a622587d123822b2328.traefik.default, not rpi`

How to push docker images to a remote using self-signed certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another software running on my raspberry pi (`k3s`) took over the 443 port.

`docker push` first makes a request to https://rpi.home/v2/ and validates the certificate, which is normally served by the `registry` container. However, if `k3s` server is running, it serves the `/v2` url and provides a completely different certificate.

The solution was to map a different port to 443 of the container.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are listening on port 443. For this to work, you need to change a few things:

1. Add a domain, even if it's localdomain, to the hostname on your network. This needs to resolve so make sure you can connect to something like `rpi.localdomain`. If there's no domain in the beginning of the image path, and no port (which you don't need for 443), then it's treated as a username on Docker Hub.
2. Rebuild your certificate with that name.
3. Make sure you store the certificate in that name, not `/etc/docker/certs.d/rpi:5000/` but `/etc/docker/certs.d/rpi.localdomain/` or whatever the domain name is. Putting it in a directory named 5000 but connecting to 443 means it wasn't used.
4. Setup a self signed CA, separate from the key.

For step 4, here's an example of my own script for setting up certs:

```
certdir="certs"
cert_host="registry"
cert_san="DNS:localhost,DNS:$(hostname)"
for ip in $(ip a | grep inet | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1 -d/); do
  cert_san="${cert_san},IP:$ip"
done

if [ ! -d "$certdir" ]; then
  mkdir -p "$certdir"
fi

# setup a CA key
if [ ! -f "$certdir/ca-key.pem" ]; then
  openssl genrsa -out "${certdir}/ca-key.pem" 4096
fi

# setup a CA cert
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 \
  -subj "/CN=Local CA" \
  -key "${certdir}/ca-key.pem" \
  -sha256 -out "${certdir}/ca.pem"

# setup a host key
if [ ! -f "${certdir}/key.pem" ]; then
  openssl genrsa -out "${certdir}/key.pem" 2048
fi

# create a signing request
extfile="${certdir}/extfile"
openssl req -subj "/CN=${cert_host}" -new -key "${certdir}/key.pem" \
   -out "${certdir}/${cert_host}.csr"
echo "subjectAltName = ${cert_san}" >${extfile}

# create the host cert
openssl x509 -req -days 365 \
   -in "${certdir}/${cert_host}.csr" -extfile "${certdir}/extfile" \
   -CA "${certdir}/ca.pem" -CAkey "${certdir}/ca-key.pem" -CAcreateserial \
   -out "${certdir}/cert.pem"
```

In the above script, the `ca.pem` is what gets copied to `/etc/docker/certs.d/${registry}/ca.crt`.

Comment: After going through the steps replacing `rpi` with `rpi.local`, I get this error when pushing: `Get "https://rpi.local/v2/": dialing rpi.local:443 with direct connection: resolving host rpi.local: lookup rpi.local on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving`. Note: the name `rpi.local` works on my LAN (I can ping it and ssh into it) - I believe it's exposed via mDNS.

Comment: Docker typically doesn't talk to mDNS, each container has it's own localhost, so connectivity to that is problematic. Look for your DNS server in /etc/resolv.conf or add an entry to /etc/hosts.

Comment: So I figured out that `rpi.home` is a non mDNS name, I can use that. Now this is the error I get: `docker push rpi.home/test-image` `Get "https://rpi.home/v2/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`. These are the steps I did:
   1. created key and certificate with the `rpi.home` domain
   2. started the `registry` image on the rpi configured with the new key and certificate
   3. copied the certificate to my PC, to `/etc/docker/certs.d/rpi.home/ca.crt`

Comment: Try building the cert with a separate CA. I'm not sure the self signed cert can be loaded as a CA.

Comment: The issue was the wrong location.. the cert should be copied to `.docker/certs.d/rpi.home/` instead of `/etc/docker/certs.d/rpi.home`. I believe this is because I use Docker Desktop and not directly running Docker Engine. I also needed to restart Docker Desktop (contradictory to the linked docker documentation). After these steps, push works.

Comment: Docker Desktop changes everything since you're not working on the host of the docker engine, it's running inside of a VM, and you need to inject that config into the VM. The steps all describe what to do for the docker engine running on Linux.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, they helped me a lot figuring out the issue.